# Как собрать проект в один deb пакет

Tags: c++, qtcreator, deb

Доброго времени суток всем. Сделал себе горе проект в QT Creator. В итоге наступил час расплаты, надо собрать этот проект в один deb пакет, чтобы в дальнейшем его устанавливать и запускать на linux машинах.
Пытался это сделать по статьям в интернете, но ничего не получается, как примерное описание действий использовал https://habr.com/ru/post/137233/, но ничего не получилось.
Расскажите пожалуйста максимально доступно как выполнить данный процесс, так как с программирование практически не знаком.

Comment: систему сборки какую используете?

Comment: Никакую, я пытался понять этот процесс. Но там у меня все мертво.

Comment: чего? а как вы тогда программу собираете?

Comment: Я прошу рассказать как это сделать и что мне для этого нужно. Некую инструкцию по которой "step by step" я получу нужный результат.

Comment: вы напоминаете людей типа: я изучаю `c` уже 5 минут, подскажите с чего начать написание `blokchain`... Какой `deb` пакет вы собираетесь создать, если даже не понимаете как собираете саму программу (хотя я так и не понял собираете ли что-то вообще). Какой step-by-step вы хотите, если даже не понимаете базовые вещи?

Comment: По сути так оно есть.